# Substitute for Scanner when using Sockets

Tags: java, sockets, java.util.scanner

Is there a better substitute for Scanner class when using sockets? i am getting really tired of the .next() and .nextLine() that are really annoying to work with because they skip lines all the time.

Comment: Use DataOutputStream and DataInputStream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `InputStreamReader` along with `BufferedReader`

**Eg:**

```
Socket s = new Socket("10.0.0.1",4444);

InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

String str = new String();

while ((str = br.readLine())!=null){


    System.out.println(str);

 }
```